# Grand piano has one damper malfunction

Tags: piano, repair

I am a part time piano technician. While tuning a client's piano, I came across one note that sustains even after key is released.

I immediately spotted one damper that does not come down firmly on the strings. I removed the damper and tried adjusting the wire but no luck. I even attempted to swap with the adjacent damper but no luck.

Please share your thoughts and experience and recommendations on the issue.

Comment: Assuming this is still an issue after almost 2 years, what is the brand, model and style of the piano? (Upright Yamaha SU7, for example...) Also, pictures would be helpful.